# asp.net c# sotreprocedure thread safe

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading

Just 1 question with regard to this post
[Is a MySQL procedure thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474980/is-a-mysql-procedure-thread-safe)

Currently, I have a stored_procedure (mysql) that will search available serial key (unique) and attach to individual user.

Therefore, there is two statement (select and update)

Therefore, I would like to check does stored_procedure or mysql process 1 at a time. Or multiple user can use stored_procedure at the same time. As I am afraid there might a conflict if two user using the stored_procdure at the same time.

From the post it seems that mysql will prevent multiple user enter procedure. And there will be a queue from there. If that is the case I wont need to write a thread safe code. (**Only 1 stored procedure access the data** other transaction wont updating the database)

Regard
Benson

Comment: Ref. [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) - without an explicit transaction, MySQL [normally] uses an autocommit mode; this is around *individual* SQL statements, as might be found *inside* the SP. It does **not** extend to the large code context. Use explicit transactions as required. Depending on the SP and operations, it might be the case that MySQL "prevents concurrency" by taking a larger lock - but this depends upon the exact operation(s) and should *not* be relied upon without stronger semantic guarantees.

Comment: Please take time to *read the answer in the linked question again* - "a given procedure will only be atomic if [and only if] you use the appropriate transaction level". (It's not actually the SP that is atomic, it is the operations against the data, inside the SP, that *may* be atomic with the appropriate transaction scope and isolation usage.)

Comment: Hmm. I think I am confuse. When multiple user request information from the application (Example Page_load inside the cs file). Does IIS process 1 at a time (Once user A has finished, do User B) or multiple at 1 go (Both User A and B will exceute the code at the same time)? Because I need to retrieve certain information from the database and unique assign to individual). I am afraid that (A and B user enter the function together and draw the same data from the database).

Comment: IIS *can* and *does* process multiple connections concurrently. Furthermore, in a real environment there may be multiple IIS servers running (meaning the code cannot even assume that it is running on a different App Domain in the same process or on the same machine). The problem being addressed probably can/should probably be handled by relying on transactions - or changing the design such that optimistic concurrency and conflict resolution can be used. *tldr; use [Transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html).*

Comment: user2864740 --> Thanks for the suggestion. Do you have conflic resolution explanation (As in theory and what are the things i need to take note?) Secondly, what is tldr? Lastly, can explain a bit more in depth with regard to , in a real environment there may be multiple IIS servers running.